# Visual Studio 2010 - Web deployment project includes framework DLLs

Tags: visual-studio-2010, deployment, msbuild

I have just upgraded a solution with two web deployment projects from VS 2008 to 2010 (upgrading all the projects to .net 4.0 as I went).

I installed the new VS2010 web deployment projects to allow me to open my old build projects (these build up my web sites, clean up a few files and zip them for upload).

I've got these working again, but when I look at the built files, all the referenced .net framework files (e.g. System.Web.dll etc) have been included in the deployed site.  Does anybody know why this might be happening and how to turn it off?

Comment: I am not able to repro this based on the info here.

Comment: Open the .csproj file with a text editor and see what's in. chances are you can find a clue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059118/reference-dlls-in-asp-net-without-bin-or-gac   check this..might help u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are using a component (DLL) which is using that files probably by needing specific file version of some framework libraries. VS will automatically copy dependencies of a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're using .Net framework Client profile version. Please check the .Net framework version selected for upgraded projects under Project properties.

Here is the MSDN article on .Net framework client profile: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I checked through all my projects, and all are targeting .net Framework 4.0, not the client profile.

Answer (score 0):

One reason could be the `Copy Local = True` property of the referenced .net framework files.

Comment: Cheers.  Checked that already, and it isn't set.  Doing a publish via visual studio does not include all these files...

Comment: Can you upload somewhere the .sln?