# how to move the code-behind Assemblies/DLLs to a different folder than /BIN with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, dll, assemblies, bin

How can I move the code-behind Assemblies/DLLs to a different folder than /BIN with ASP.NET or group/merge those DLLs in /Bin to one DLLs file? I want to separate DLLs files as its purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ILMerge` to merge all your DLL files into one. http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx

Comment: it is interting so much But how can I use it .I  just download from MS. and i have no idea to do the next step

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this question inre to storing the DLL outside of the BIN folder:

[Reference DLLs in ASP.NET without \Bin or GAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059118/reference-dlls-in-asp-net-without-bin-or-gac)