# Where does an ASP.NET WebSite or Web Application store Referenced DLLs

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, dll, .net-assembly

In simple terms - I have a .net library A.dll. A.dll uses B.dll & C.dll.

Both B & C are not .Net Libraries. How do I use A.dll in my web app?

So I have the dll file - Jedox.Palo.Comm.dll (A) that I have added as a reference to a ASP.NET Webapp. This DLL in turn uses 2 more files, 1. libpalo_ng.dll (B) & 2. libpalo2.dll (C).
These two libpalo dlls are not necessarily COM components/assemblies. So they can't be added directly as a reference.

Instead I have to place them in the same folder as the Jedox..dll
In normal appls, forms etc the folder is Debug/bin. But in webapps, where should I place these dll files, since it has to be in the same folder as the Jedox...dll

Also, creating a new folder bin, and putting all three dlls there and adding references doesn't work for some reason!
Thanks in advace!!

Indrajit

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay so this did the trick, a rather simple solution
I just copied the two dlls - libpalo_ng.dll & libpalo2.dll to my SysWOW64 fodler
And its all working well now.

Thanks for all the responses!

Answer (score 4):

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059118/reference-dlls-in-asp-net-without-bin-or-gac) for some ideas.

The short answer to your question is that the equivalent folder of `Debug/bin` in a web application is `[root]/bin`.

When you reference DLLs from VS, you can set `Copy Local` to true for a DLL and it will bi copies in the `[root]/bin` folder when you publish the web application.

If you want to store the DLLs inside your solution, you can make a folder with a different name than `bin` and put the DLLs in it and then when you `Add References` select browse and reference them from your solution's folder.

Comment: Ok so couple of things...
1. libpalo_ng.dll & libpalo2.dll are not .Net libraries
2. I have already tried placing all 3 files in a folder bin and building thereafter. I somehow still get the same error.
3. I have tried adding references via web.config to all 3. The libpalo* fail for the same reason as above.
So in short, I have a .Net dll A that references two more dlls.
How do I use A in a web application!

Comment: Here is the error when I view the aspx page:
[FileNotFoundException: The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)]

Comment: you are using .net 4.0, right? You can reference non-.net dlls in a web project. The documentation of the dll that you referenced should tell you if you need to include it's dependencies in the web.config or as a project reference or both.

Comment: That's the catch, these dlls were written for .net 2.0 so I'm using 2.0. In any case, can you direct me on how to reference non-.net dlls?

Comment: also, simply putting the two non .net dlls in the bin/Debug folder for console app works. But doing so in a web app does not!

Comment: referencing dlls in .net 2.0 web.config is different than in .net 4.0 web.config. You can use both methods in the same web.config. Manually putting dlls in the bin folder of a web application does not help, you have to reference the dlls from the project or from web.config (depending on the type of the dll)

Comment: Okay so this did the trick, a rather simple solution I just copied the two dlls - libpalo_ng.dll & libpalo2.dll to my SysWOW64 fodler And its all working well now.

Thanks for all the responses!